# local variable 'params' referenced before assignment in django

Tags: django, django-views

Here's my view

```
def ATFinfo(Request):
    # inputdata = Request.GET.get('inputdata')
    url = 'www.google.com'
    req = Request.GET
    print("hi",req)
    req_list = list(dict(req).values())
    print("list",req_list)
    params_count = len(req_list)
    print('params_count', params_count)
    if params_count > 0:
        for i in range(params_count):
            params = params + req_list[i+1][0] + '=' + req_list[i+1][1] + '&' 
        url = url + params

        print('paramfinal',params)
    return render(Request, 'hello/ATF_Dashboard.html')
```

In this view i'm getting error **local variable 'params' referenced before assignment** in line `params = params + req_list[i+1][0] + '=' + req_list[i+1][1] + '&'`
How to solve that issue? Also i'm not able to understand what is the problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tried to use `params` here specifically the expression `params + req_list...`, the variable `params` isn't defined yet.

```
for i in range(params_count):
    params = params + req_list[i+1][0] + '=' + req_list[i+1][1] + '&'
```

You have to define it first:

```
params = ""
for i in range(params_count):
    params = params + req_list[i+1][0] + '=' + req_list[i+1][1] + '&'
```

You could also use `+=` operator:

```
params += req_list[i+1][0] + '=' + req_list[i+1][1] + '&'
```

Also based on the pasted code, take note that this line:

```
url = url + params
```

Doesn't add anything in the logic as `url` isn't used after that (unless the pasted code is not the complete version).